# Back button getting disappear in android device ionic2

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]

I am facing issue of back button disappearing in my ionic2 app. 
below are the steps after which issue is occuring

1. Main screen - click on icon (page 1)

2.popover will come with 3 choices (popover - page 2)

3.select any option and new page will open (here back button is visible-page 3 ) click on '+' and go to new page(page 4)

4.come back to  page 3 and back button is getting disappeared.

I have not written any specific code to show / hide back button as its working properly as per the default behaviour this issue only happening on android device not on ios. how to solve this?

Comment: what is this popover you speak of is it a modal? Can you give some info about how you are navigating?

Comment: there is a page in my app which m opening using popover control
below is code


 let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('PopoverPage', { parameters });
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });

Comment: Did you use something like this when navigating from modal ?
      this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(SecondPage);

Comment: No . this is what i have used.

this.navCtrl.push(strPagename, { parameters });

Comment: this.navCtrl.getRootNav().push(strPagename,{parameters}); use it like this and check

Comment: its gicing error property getRootNav doesnot exist for NavController

Answer (score 0):

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController public appCtrl: App) {
  }

function(){
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().navCtrl.push(strPagename,{params: 
     params});
}
```

Read about navigation with overlay components here like modals ,popover,etc.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Also getRootNav will be deprecated soon and we should use getRootNavById

Comment: hello Mayank . thank you for the detailed information , but i think i found the problem.
below is my function where i have written "this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); " to close popover. when we going to page 3 ,if i comment this then back button working fine.

 navigatePush(strPagename){
  this.navCtrl.push(strPagename, { parameters });
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

now my question is how can we close popover automatically if user comes back to main page from page 3 by clicking back button.

Comment: You can use life cycle hooks and just close it with dismiss when you are leaving the view instead  . You can use IonicViewDidLeave .https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/